Is Secure Capital Bank Legit?
Just curious due to it being a private bank? Want to know if it is recognized?

If you have to ask, assume that it isn't. If you want to research it, past answers have discussed some ways to investigate.

This question is similar to: How to check if a bank is legit. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

No. It's a fictional bank in a video game. As far as I can tell there is no real bank by that name. Whoever is trying to get you to transact with it is almost certainly a scammer.

The game in question being Payday 3, released in 2023. Some screenshots

What's going on, James Kirk Passport level shenanigans?

@Joshua despite being a Trekkie I don't know what you are referring to....

@Vicky: Unfortunately the source is gone now. :( What happened is a scammer got duped by a passport that said James T Kirk, using a frame from Star Trek II as the passport image.

The passport image itself has survived due to somebody else using it. http://toshogu.blogspot.com/2007/11/ image http://photos1.blogger.com/blogger/6096/2794/1600/kirk.jpg

Some steps to take to figure out whether a bank is legitimate:

Google it. In this case Google turned up nothing. A very bad sign. A real bank is going to have some footprint in Google. If nothing at all turns up there isn't any point in checking further, it's some kind of scam. Look for online reviews. The absence of any reviews is a giant red flag. The reviews themselves may not mean much, since they can be astro-turfed.

Suppose you found a web site. Keep in mind that for an investment of $20 or so anybody can set up a website and a domain name. Poke around on the website. Do the links all work? Do they take you to actual information? Does the site name any corporate officers? Does it provide phone numbers? A physical location? If those are missing steer clear.

Supposing the web site seems to check out, does the bank have a verified physical presence in your country? If not, consider how you would proceed if you had a dispute with them. Do you have the resources to hire a lawyer in the bank's home country? Do you trust the legal system in that country?

Check with the financial authorities that regulate banking in your country and the bank's home country. In the US you can lookup FDIC insured banks online. Credit Unions are regulated separately, but you can look those up online too. Be aware though that some countries will license any business that pays the appropriate fees, and registration is no guarantee that it's a legitimate business (see point 3).



Somewhere around 2.2: do a "whois" lookup on the domain name records. Information like where the site is nominally based and how long it has been held by its current owners is public, and there are a number of tools either standalone or at domain name vendor sites that will display this. If the site isn't based where the webpage says the company is based, be suspicious. If the domain's current owners have had it for less than a few years be very suspicious.

There's a "Secured Capital Banking" (a "a multinational regional financial services provider" ahah) which says they are regulated by the UK's FCA. Bizarrely no trace of them in the FCA's register. They also have 2597 branches (but no branch locator), and despite being "25 years in banking" and that many branches, they only have "5430 happy customers" and "40467 successful projects". Scaaaaaaaaaaaam.
